# PHP Mysql DELETE if row was empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I have this 4 fields on my table. p1 p2 p3 p4
gameID is the row table. So only that row should be deleted.
So when it update the `playe1 = ''` it will delete the row table.

Note that it will delete only if the p1 p2 p3 p4 is empty.

Is my code if else correct? it update the row player1 to empty but it did not delete.

```
if($p1 == $email_val){
    $sql_update_player = mysql_query("UPDATE game SET player1='' WHERE gameID='$gameID' ") or die ( mysql_error() );
$stat = "1";
    if(empty($p1) and empty($p2) and empty($p3) and empty($p4) ){
        $sqlDelGame = mysql_query("DELETE FROM game WHERE gameID='$gameID'") or die ( mysql_error() );
        echo "Game deleted";
    }
}
```

Comment: be **VERY** careful with `empty()`. There's a LOT of things in PHP that qualify as `empty()` but aren't, and wouldn't be by any other intelligent/sane language. Plus, your delete code would never fire, since you've already enforced the `$p1` has to be equal to some other value. if that other value is never "empty", the delete code can't fire.

Comment: so should i put it something like this `$p1 == ''`?

Comment: Are you sure all `$p1, $p2, $p3, $p4` are all empty? There's no place in your code that shows what values are stored in those variables

Comment: well, `if($p1 == $email_val){
    $sql_update_player = mysql_query("UPDATE game SET player1='' WHERE gameID='$gameID' ") or die ( mysql_error() );
$stat = "1";`

this part is supposed to remove a value in $p1, instead of delete i used update and replaced its content with just '' the same procedure will happen to p2 p3 and p4 what i want to happen is delete the row when all Ps are empty
`

Comment: What part of that is supposed to empty the $p1 variable? You are updating a table row, not touching the values of any of the $pX variables

Comment: the if statement compares if $p1 value is similar with $email_val when they do i update player1 field with '' , im not sure if updating it with that value will consider it being empty, for every instance where $email_val is similar to $pX they are replaced with the said value. when they are all considered empty this is when i want it to delete the row

Comment: Take a look at @Puggan Se's answer. That's probably what you want (just add your extra condition that matches the gameID)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete games that dosn't have any players yet, you can run:

```
DELETE FROM game
WHERE player1 = ''
  AND player2 = ''
  AND player3 = ''
  AND player4 = '';
```